# Treat multiple sound input sources as one virtual microphone

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, jack

I want to automate my home using [Jasper](http://jasperproject.github.io).

To do that, the [documentation](http://jasperproject.github.io/documentation/installation) tells me to edit the ALSA config file so a usb card will have index 0. I want to use multiple microphones spread around my house. I have 7 cheap usb sound cards. How can I configure ALSA or other software to mix these microphones as one virtual microphone?

Comment: I don't think this can be done at the `ALSA` level,  you'll probably need something like `jack` or `pluseaudio`

Comment: Okay, how would I do that with pulseaudio or jack. Have googled, but most questions are about recording.